# Forge + Git + Laravel issue

Tags: php, git, laravel, forge

I have Laravel forge set up with Bitbucket.

I pushed some code to bitbucket and it dumped an error saying that there was an problem with fetching stuff from bitbucket. So I opened up my website to see if it would give any errors.

The website wouldn't load properly and it turned out that one of the files that had a name of `Display.php` had been renamed to `display.php`.

How is that possible to have happened? This file is outside the `public` directory.

I checked to logs to see if anyone else has connected to the server (thinking it got hacked), but nothing suspicious in the logs.

Has anyone ever had a similar problem?

Comment: Is it possible that you had renamed the file after committing it to your repository? On some operating systems and even IDEs, changing the file  from "display.php" to "Display.php" may not register, so when the code gets pulled down from the repo by another user/process, the actual filename is different.

Comment: Is your local machine Windows or Mac OS? Because those OSs are case insensitive and that causes a problem when you deploy to a case sensitive server (e.g. Linux).

Comment: thanks for replies guys. The problem was with the namespacing. Apparently the file had been named lowercase and I was using the uppercase classname, but it was working for a while until I imported a Facebook SDK via composer, which for some reason changed the way namespacing used to work on my code.. odd.

Comment: It's possible that, you gave that name accidentally, because your OS is probably `windows` and windows didn't complaint about the lower case name so you didn't realize your mistake but after you upload the code to server, `linux` is unhappy. It's a common mistake.

Comment: I'm using OS X, and I've just posted what happened... (which is odd in its way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted out.

The problem was that, initially it was named `display.php` (a typo) and it worked fine, until I installed Facebook SDK via composer.

I have a feeling it's something to do with types of `namespacing` (PSRs).

If I remove Facebook SDK, then `display.php` works fine, otherwise it throws an error.